# All children of a node to appear on same line in output

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML which looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD Journal Publishing DTD v2.3 20070202//EN"
    "http://dtd.nlm.nih.gov/publishing/2.3/journalpublishing.dtd">
<article>
    <front>
        <!-- Some metadata -->
    </front>
    <body>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vel metus felis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas <italic>habitasse</italic> venenatis.</p>
        <!-- More elements -->
    </body>
    <back>
        <ref-list>
            <ref id="id-28299">
                <nlm-citation citation-type="journal">
                    <person-group person-group-type="author">
                        <name>
                            <surname>Bar</surname>
                            <given-names>F</given-names>
                        </name>
                    </person-group>
                    <article-title>Baz</article-title>
                    <source>Made up</source>
                    <year>1970</year>
                    <volume>27</volume>
                    <issue>(4)</issue>
                    <fpage>3</fpage>
                    <lpage>7</lpage>
                    <pub-id pub-id-type="doi">http://some.url.org</pub-id>
                </nlm-citation>
            </ref>
            <!-- More ref entries -->
        </ref-list>
    </back>
</article>
```

I need to transform it so that `ref` elements (and **only** the ref elements, everything else must remain as it is) are each contained on a single line with a space between elements. I.E.

```
<ref id="id-28299"><nlm-citation citation-type="journal"> <person-group person-group-type="author"><name><surname>Bar</surname> <given-names>F</given-names></name></person-group> <article-title>Baz</article-title> <source>Made up</source> <year>1970</year> <volume>27</volume> <issue>(4)</issue> <fpage>3</fpage> <lpage>7</lpage> <pub-id pub-id-type="doi">http://some.url.org</pub-id></nlm-citation></ref>
```

I can do it by unwrapping the elements using this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ref//*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:if test="following-sibling::*"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I *want to keep* the tags. So I tried the following:

```
<xsl:template match="ref//*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element><xsl:if test="following-sibling::*"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

But now each element will appear on a different line. I've also tried using `<xsl:strip-space>` but this didn't seem to change the output at all.

Comment: Why is this important? You are outputting XML.

Comment: Have you tried it with setting the indent to "no".... `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>`. You also do need to do `<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />`, otherwise whitespace only nodes will be copied.

Comment: This is important because the whitespace only nodes are retained and create a problem when it's imported into Adobe InDesign. The plan is to apply this tansformation on import. I have tried `indent="no"` but that seems to put *everything* on a single line, which is not wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could try is to set the "indent" option to "no", and then instead of using `strip-space`, which would remove all whitespace from the input XML, have a specific template to ignore whitespace only nodes under `ref`. This would prevent them being output by the default template.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ref//*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element><xsl:if test="following-sibling::*"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ref//text()[not(normalize-space())]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 3.0 (and Saxon) have `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" suppress-indentation="ref"/>` which is designed for exactly this purpose. If you can't take advantage of that, I would suggest using indent="no", and adding whitespace between ref elements (and anywhere else you want it) "by hand" using xsl:value-of or xsl:text.